# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800701bc

Tags: ubuntu, wsl-2

Error when installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Possible solutions:

1. Enable CPU virtualization in the bios.
2. Install the linux kernel updates. (worked for me!): [Install update on linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package). After installation, open Windows PowerShell and write `wsl --set-default-version 2` and done! Problem solved!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: for me, I needed to set wsl --set-default-version to version  instead of 2
wsl --set-default-version 1

Answer (score 49):

I typed `wsl --update` and the new version of wsl is installed.
Then I installed Ubuntu by `wsl --install -d ubuntu` and it worked.

Comment: This will work irrespective of version.

Comment: running `wsl --update` seemed to do the trick. thank you!

Comment: This command should be run with administrative-level permissions.

Comment: worked with just updating wsl using first code **wsl --update**

Comment: This worked for me seems like it's the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to give another solution to this problem. In short, problem is caused by wsl kernel update package installation.

Followed up each steps as been told by this page [Manual installation steps for older versions of WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package), but still recurring the same problem while installing. How come? after clicking on wsl_update_x64.msi installation which told me kernel updated perfected but still cannot install `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` with `0x800701bc error code`. I realize kernel update info might be truth negative/failed and could try some work around manually [WSL 2 requires an update Github Issue #5014](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5014).

According to onomatopellan's answer from github, I could install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS after this work around.

```
For WSL2 you will need 2 Windows components so make sure they are already enabled:
Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
VirtualMachinePlatform

Also it seems some people have problems with the installer extracting the kernel.
You can always extract it manually with:
msiexec /a "wsl_update_x64.msi" /qb TARGETDIR="C:\temp"
and then copy the kernel file from C:\temp to C:\Windows\System32\lxss\tools

Final version shouldn't have this problem since the install comes from Windows Update.
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently found similar errors while installing Ubuntu and Kali in WSL for Windows 11:

**Ubuntu**

> WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800701bc

**Kali**

> error: 0x80370114 the operation could not be started because a required feature is not installed.

It turns out the cause was the same for both errors. WSL requires a couple `Windows Features` to be turned on and in this scenario the feature `Virtual Machine Platform` was not.

---

**Solution**

1. Open `Turn Windows features on or off`
2. Check `Virtual Machine Platform` box
3. Check `Windows Subsystem for Linux` box
4. Restart

---

Distros can then be managed via a Command Prompt as per the quick list below:

**List the currently installed distributions**

`wsl --list`

**List the distros available to be installed**

`wsl --list --online`

```
The following is a list of valid distributions that can be installed.
Install using 'wsl.exe --install <Distro>'.

NAME                                   FRIENDLY NAME
Ubuntu                                 Ubuntu
Debian                                 Debian GNU/Linux
kali-linux                             Kali Linux Rolling
Ubuntu-18.04                           Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Ubuntu-20.04                           Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Ubuntu-22.04                           Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
OracleLinux_8_5                        Oracle Linux 8.5
OracleLinux_7_9                        Oracle Linux 7.9
SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-15-SP4    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP4
openSUSE-Leap-15.4                     openSUSE Leap 15.4
openSUSE-Tumbleweed                    openSUSE Tumbleweed
```

**Install a distro**

Picked `Ubuntu` from the listed names in the **NAME** column on the left:

`wsl --install Ubuntu`

**Set a distro as the default**

`wsl --set-default Ubuntu`

**Start WSL with the default distro**

`wsl`

**To uninstall a distro**

`wsl --unregister Ubuntu`

---

**Environment**
**CPU:** AMD Ryzen 9 6900HX
**OS:** Windows 11 Home 22H2 - 64-bit